# How to run a python script in Node.js once the node.js application has been packaged using 'pkg .'

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, node.js

I am trying to run a python script using spawn child_process. I have managed to get this to work when running nodemon app.js, however I would like to package my node application and have it run a python script. Once I have packaged the application using:

```
pkg .
```

it seems to be able to run the code as there are no errors returned, however the python script does not seem to work. The Python script creates some test data and saves it to a .csv file which node will then look at using Tail.

Python Script:

```
import random 
import time
import datetime
import math
import sys

cwd = ""

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    cwd = sys.argv[1]
    print(cwd)

x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
while(True):
    x = x + 0.1
    y += 1
    f =  open( cwd + "./public/data.csv", "a")
    
    csv_writer = writer(f)
    
    num1 = random.randrange(50,120)
    num2 = random.randrange(50,120)
    num3 = math.sin(x)
    
    num4 = str(datetime.datetime.now().time()).split('.')[0] + "." + str(datetime.datetime.now().time()).split('.')[1][0:3]
    print(num4)
    csv_writer.writerow([num1,num2,num3,num4])
    f.close()
```

The node tail set up in app.js:

```
tail = new Tail("./public/data.csv");
```

Here is my code to spawn the child process:

```
router.post("/testing/start", function (req, res) {
    /**
    * Start the python script. The python script will start generating the data.
    * @memberof TestingRoutes.PythonScripts
    * @function
    * @name post
    * @param '/testing/start' The url
    * @instance
    */
    python = spawn('python', ['./test.py', process.cwd()]);
    testing_status = true;
    res.send("success");
})
```

My thoughts are that it's something to do with where the script is located in relation to where the executable is located. Or it is something to do with where the tail is looking. However I have looked on activity monitor to see if there is a Python process running after I have started the script and there doesn't seem to be any python program running. Is starting a python script from a node even possible in a node executable?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I which line u are getting the error?

Comment: `classList` is not a property of a jQuery object. Read the docs: https://api.jquery.com/removeClass & https://api.jquery.com/addClass. Also `exec()` too, but I have no idea what you're expecting it to do in the context you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's method to add a class is called [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
jQuery's method to remove a class is called [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

```
$("#photo-container h1").addClass("animate-out")
```

otherwise use `.get(0)` or `[0]` to retrieve the HTMLElement from the jQuery object before using JavaScript's `Element.classList` constructor.

```
$("#photo-container h1")[0].classList.add("animate-out")
```

Same goes for the first line.
Additionally, if you want to assign a listener to `"animationend"` (or `"transitionend"` if you use CSS3 `transition`) - than do so:

```
const $H1 = $("#photo-container h1");

$H1.removeClass("animate animate-out");
$H1.on("animationend", function() {
  // Do something once the CSS3 keyframes animation ends
  if ( !$H1.is('.animate-out') ) {
    $H1.addClass("animate-out");
  } 
});
```

Comment: @mbh16 Are you copy pasting code from somewhere without understanding what it does?